# std::cin is taking two different variable types from console and 'storing' the second type for later?

Tags: c++, cin

I am writing a calculator program. It first asks for a number (stored as double), then an operator symbol (ex. '/' or '+')(stored as char), then a second number (stored as double) to apply the operation to the first.

```
double number1 = 0;
cout << "What operation would you like to perform?" << endl;
char operation = a;
cin >> operation;
```

I then use switch. If it reads a '+' it will continue on

```
double adding(double& number1)
{
    cout << "What number would you like to add to " << number1 << "?" << endl;
    double number2 = 0;
    cin >> number2;
    number1 = number1 + number2;
    return number1;
}
```

It still works if you input +20 for the char operation. It doesn't cause an error and will successfully add 20 to your initial number even though + is a char and 20 is an int. It will skip the `cin >> number2;` section of the code and take the 20 you already typed from the `cin >> operation`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It doesn't skip the `cin >> number2`. `cin >> operation` reads ONE character (the `+`). The next operation to take place using `cin` is `cin >> number2`, which will continue from where it left off. i.e., the `20` is still left to read.

Comment: So I could loop the entire thing, write out 20/20+8.1-33 and it would execute fine? taking 20, then /, then 20, then+.... as long as I type it out so 20 is input where it asks for integers and symbols for characters?

Comment: Yes. You really don't want to ask the user 3 questions to enter something like `50+20` anyway. You can simply write `cin >> number1 >> operation >> number2;` then switch on `operation` and you already have both numbers usable.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many values can be read like this? Also, can you copy paste your first comment so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't skip the `cin >> number2`. `cin >> operation` reads ONE character (the `+`). The next operation to take place using `cin` is `cin >> number2`, which will continue from where it left off. i.e., the `20` is still left to read.

You really don't want to ask the user 3 questions to enter something like `50+20` anyway. You can simply write `cin >> number1 >> operation >> number2;` then switch on operation and you already have both numbers usable. There is no limit (afaik) to the amount of concatenations using `>>`

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is a stream object representing `stdin` or the Standard Input stream. The `>>` operator (I'm going to call it the "extraction operator") extracts characters from the stream and writes to a variable. With `std::cin`, it'll attempt to pull what it needs from what's already in the stream, but if it runs out of those, it'll wait for user input from the console.

In fact, if you're running this program from a bash shell, you can tell the program to read `stdin` from a file instead:

```
./a.out < input_file.txt
```

All of your `std::cin >> ...` statements will get "skipped" as you say. What's actually happening is it's reading the next value from the stream (which in this case is the contents of input_file.txt) without waiting for user input.

Since when `std::cin` waits for user input it'll keep reading your input until you press enter, you can enter more characters than the immediate `std::cin >>` statement is looking for. This is what's happening here.